# Вычислить среднее расстояние по m ближайшим соседям для каждой точки

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, python-3.6

У меня есть df (2178x4). Надо вычислить среднее расстояние по  m  ближайшим соседям для каждой точки. Т.е. если  m=3 , нужно выбрать трёх ближайших соседей, сложить расстояния до них и поделить на три. Затем отсортировать полученные значения по возрастанию и построить график.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('quake_clear.csv')
df.head()
```

PS Данные (CSV файл) можно [скачать отсюда](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ZJIzRlr5MqpjQI_OH7g8q3ivQO_WHzy/view?usp=sharing/quake_clear.csv)

Comment: приведите пример входных и выходных данных. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Добавил скрин. просто я новичок, пока не знаю как генерировать код здесь(

Comment: Вставьте код в вопрос, выделите его и нажмите `{}` на панели инструментов.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! но почему у меня не выводит результат?

Comment: @ArmanHakobyan, OK, со входными данными разобрались, теперь осталось понять что вы хотите получить... Вы хотите сгруппировать точки в кластеры?

Comment: В целом задача такая необходимо найти эвристику выбора параметров DBSCAN(eps=?, min_samples=?). eps-границы окрестности, т.е. максимальное расстояние до соседа. mean_samples- минимальное число соседей, необходимое, чтобы точка стала корневой. Существуют эвристики для выбора  m  (min_samples) и  ϵ  (eps). 1)Выберите  m, 2)Вычислите среднее расстояние по  m  ближайшим соседям для каждой точки. Т.е. если  m=3 , нужно выбрать трёх ближайших соседей, сложить расстояния до них и поделить на три.3)Сортируем полученные значения по возрастанию и строим график как в локтевом методе.4)из график выбраь ϵ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял задачу...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\quake_clear.csv').dropna(how='all')

# pairwise distance for all points
d = pairwise_distances(df[['Latitude','Longitude']])

# ignore distance to itself    
d[d==0] = np.inf

# compute the average distance to 3 nearest neighbours    
y = np.sort(d, axis=1)[:, :3].mean(axis=1)

# plot...
plt.plot(range(len(y)), y)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да да, это то что нужно было, я все понял! Спасибо огромное!!

Answer (score 1):

Если это учебное задание, то самому запрограммировать, как это указано выше - пожалуй самый лучший путь к знаниям. А вот если вы используете этот метод для решения какой-либо реальной задачи, то я бы все-таки рекомендовал к использованию 
KNeighborsClassifier из scikit-learn.

Подключается вот так:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
```

Там и метрики можно выбрать, и оптимизировать скорость поиска решения и подобрать разные расстояния для параметров - в общем все, что может потребоваться для работы.

Comment: не совсем понятно как обучать эту модель. Т.е. что указывать в качестве `y` при вызове `.fit(X, y)`?

Comment: Классический пример из документации   X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X, y) 
KNeighborsClassifier(...)
print(neigh.predict([[1.1]]))
print(neigh.predict_proba([[0.9]]))  (Cорри,  кажется тут тег code не используется, но в примере видно, что указывать как X и y).

Comment: Пример я понял - я не понял откуда автор возьмёт значения для переменной “y”

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Задание учебное, буду постараться решать сам, но иногда не получается))

Comment: @MaxU есть учебник "А Мюллер, введение в машинное обучение с помощью Python" в котором в разных алгоритмах часто  используется метод fit(), и там можно понять откуда берется y. Если что я могу отправить учебник на твою почту)

Comment: @ArmanHakobyan, если у вас есть заведеомо размеченные (с указанным номером кластера) данные для обучения, то непонятно зачем вам DBSCAN... ;-)